# I have a question about how to tell whether tx is 'transfer', 'call', 'create' or 'destruct'

Tags: transactions, transfer

I want to distinguish between the types of Ethereum TX.

In the Ethercan, That is distinguish tx type like, transfer, contract create, contract destruct, contract call and etc...

**so, I check trace data using geth node, it show internal tx call type but, not show external tx call type.**
like below..

- transfer case :
  https://etherscan.io/tx/0xecf61e7455638726cd0624cc2cc81a66d295d51cd5c6fe6a6353e1d19f209989

```
  {
    "result": {
      "blockHash": "0x69fb80fe792ceae0aacc76632405015859047298538602a58433184aca50f5b0",
      "blockNumber": "0xcdfe92",
      "transactionHash": "0xecf61e7455638726cd0624cc2cc81a66d295d51cd5c6fe6a6353e1d19f209989",
      "error": null,
      "from": "0xb5d85cbf7cb3ee0d56b3bb207d5fc4b82f43f511",
      "to": "0x16dd35674a22395236b375a1327d98668521d203",
      "input": "0x",
      "value": "0x10d8c303a52f3000",
      "output": "0x",
      "gas": "0x0",
      "gasUsed": "0x0",
      "gasPrice": "0x2bd16ee12b",
      "intrinsicGas": "0x5208"
    }
  },
```

- contract call..?
- The depth1 data of the result does not know the func type.

```
{
    "result": {
      "blockHash": "0x69fb80fe792ceae0aacc76632405015859047298538602a58433184aca50f5b0",
      "blockNumber": "0xcdfe92",
      "transactionHash": "0xa8e977b9a0271b3495d160fc32745fae6e5e25f3c9f285d6c3df37d01e8bee34",
      "error": "execution reverted",
      "from": "0x848d47d6a68fc0ce61e234257fa7024c59d331dc",
      "to": "0x642bffb61457fefa2fdd57c13aa24a2eaf0e5eea",
      "input": "0xcff293aa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000967da4048cd07ab37855c090aaf366e4ce1b9f48000000000000000000000000dd75cd55c1367b3d2d928c6181eea46999d24a7200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000617969f400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c498bc44c5900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008166e449e5f2b069696",
      "value": "0x0",
      "calls": [
        {
          "callType": "STATICCALL",
          "from": "0x642bffb61457fefa2fdd57c13aa24a2eaf0e5eea",
          "to": "0x9b7dad79fc16106b47a3dab791f389c167e15eb0",
          "input": "0x0902f1ac",
          "output": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019f3cdb358839c2167c6c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016070ee374668882620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061796892",
          "gas": "0x5500e",
          "gasUsed": "0x9c8"
        }
      ],
      "output": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b556e69737761705632526f757465723a20494e53554646494349454e545f4f55545055545f414d4f554e54000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "gas": "0x57b80",
      "gasUsed": "0x2550",
      "gasPrice": "0x410174af2b",
      "intrinsicGas": "0x58b0"
    }
  },
```

so like below..., In the case of contract create tx, I checked whether the tx created or destructed it through etherscan.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd0c90722e974ba3c429c616181b7dbd8ba43c6281cfbb3342acbe4f655dcadd8

```
{
    "result": {
      "blockHash": "0x72ed3b78622accc1dc2019deeb296ce51df5ef03f9cf7f8131b20031793f1484",
      "blockNumber": "0xc65d54",
      "transactionHash": "0xd0c90722e974ba3c429c616181b7dbd8ba43c6281cfbb3342acbe4f655dcadd8",
      "error": null,
      "from": "0xf15968a096fc8f47650001585d23bee819b5affb",
      "to": "0x6342b5198bec14c2083eff55005907e2be921ef6",
      "input": "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",
      "value": "0x0",
      "output": "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",
      "gas": "0x49d2d",
      "gasUsed": "0x49d2d",
      "gasPrice": "0xba43b7400",
      "intrinsicGas": "0x12f9c"
    }
  },
```

Is there a way to distinguish the tx type in external transaction?
Can it be distinguished by gasUsed or input data?
Currently, I am using python.

Comment: Not sure if this will help,  but you can (https://ethtx.info/) to decode your tx. Check out their Github (https://github.com/EthTx/ethtx) it is a Python package with core transaction decoding functions.